# How can I change path to my DB file on App.config?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, app-config

I am trying to use sql server mdf file in winForm using entity framwork 6, I do not want to install SQL Server in user's computer to use my winform application.

For this sake I added new ADO.NET entity model and choose sql database file,

now I am trying to access mdf file (which is in debug folder of my project) from App.config connection string 
my Connection string is

```
<add name="miosystem_halqaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=TOFIQ;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\miosystem_halqa.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and App.config is

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="miosystem_halqaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=TOFIQ;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\miosystem_halqa.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The code is below for testing the connection

```
  miosystem_halqaEntities db = new miosystem_halqaEntities();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var j = db.ms_user.Where(x => x.user_id > 0).Select(x=>x.user_fname).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < j.Count; i++)
        {
            label1.Text += j[i].ToString() + "\r";
        }
    }
```

I tried using ~ in my connection string but get the error

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

```
<add name="miosystem_halqaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=TOFIQ;attachdbfilename=&quot;~\miosystem_halqa.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What I am missing in connection string ? how can i use relative path etc

Comment: Are you running this on IIS ?

Comment: and where is your code that you use to open the connection ?

Comment: no, its windows form application, I am using sql server mdf file and entity framwork

Comment: I know it's winform, but are you running it on IIS ? google it...and please add the code you use to open the connection

Comment: what is `miosystem_halqaEntities` ?

Comment: The code is added and no I am not running it on IIS

Comment: miosystem_halqaEntities is DB context

Comment: The solution would be simple but you are using LINQ here, so , I am trying to figure out the solution keeping LINQ

Comment: are you calling `db.Open` somewhere ?(dumb question)

Comment: what server are you asking to host the sql file? what details did you put in the app config accordingly.. what is TOFIQ ? does that have any sql server type product on it or compact sql?

Comment: Umm...Okay..i will raise my downvote :(

Comment: zack raiya I am not calling db.open

Comment: @BugFinder TOFIQ is sql server instance name

Comment: @MohammadTofiq you are using a [user instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances) database. That's a feature of SQL Server Express. You can't *not* install SQL Server Express if you want to use this. [LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017) *also* requires SQL Server Express.

Comment: @MohammadTofiq if TOFIQ is a server instance you will need to name the server.  You probably dont need then to attach it with your connection string but just have it as a database in your instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a relative path point of view, if the mdf file is in the debug folder of your project then you shouldn't need to specifiy a path in the connection string because your code will be running from that location. Try removing the ~\ from the connection string leaving just the filename.

However, even if the path is correct I'm not sure it's going to work anyway because the database instance TOFIQ referenced in the Data Source isn't going to exist on your client's machine. As Panagiotis said, I think you will need SQL Server Express on the client machine or host the file on a server that has SQL Server installed that the client has access to.